# How to resolve "The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'never'."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to wrap a native element with a custom component, and I want to make sure if a `onload` callback is supplied that it gets called.

The trouble is I'm getting a typescript error when I try and invoke the function.

`The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'never'.`

What am I doing wrong / how do I appease typescript?

```js
export const LoadAwareImage = ({ onLoad, className, alt, ...props }: ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"img">) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <img
      onLoad={(e) => {
        setLoaded(true);
        onLoad && onLoad(e); // The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'never'.
      }}
      alt={alt}
      className={clsx(loaded && "loaded", className)}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: try onLoad={(e:any) => ....

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend you use `&&` for a general `if` statement.

This is more clear and will always be more clear for anyone reading the code, and as a bonus it fixes your issue:

```js
export const LoadAwareImage = ({ onLoad, className, alt, ...props }: ComponentPropsWithoutRef<"img">) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <img
      onLoad={(e) => {
        setLoaded(true);
        if (onLoad) onLoad(e);
      }}
      alt={alt}
      className={clsx(loaded && "loaded", className)}
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 onLoad && onLoad(e);
```

to

```
onLoad && onLoad.call(this, e);
```

[closed issue on typescript git for reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31123)